# What is the purpose of tag "guzzle.client" in guzzle client bundle in symfony2 ?

Tags: symfony, bundle, guzzle

I am using the guzzle client bundle in a symfony2 project and I checked the configuration provided here : 
https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/clients.md

```
// MyBundle/Resources/config/services.xml

<service id="example.client" class="%guzzle.client.class%">
    <tag name="guzzle.client"/>
    <argument>http://api.example.com/</argument>
</service>
```

It would be awesome if somebody can explain why we need the tag .

Comment: Is your question about tagging services in general or specifically about this tag?

Comment: This specific tag because the service will work anyway without it .. so I am just curious to know what it does ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guzzle bundle uses a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-a-compiler-pass) to add the bundle's listeners to the defined clients/services.

The compiler pass also adds the subscriptions to the guzzle plugins for your client.

The important code is here: https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ClientCompilerPass.php